# MATLAB: taking the average of two numbers in a list?

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement, for-loop, average

i'm trying to write a script that takes the average of the first two numbers and produces a new list.

for example, if i have

a = [1,2,3,4], i want it to produce b = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5
]

is there anyway of adding the two endpoints in to the loop? So far, I have:

```
for i=1:m
    betwn(i) = (values(i) + values(i+1))/2 %values is a list
    if i = m
        break
    end
end
```

and it doesn't seem to be working well...

Thanks!!

Comment: At first decide what do you want to add at end points. For 0.5 you've added 0 and for 4.5 you've added 5? It is logical for a man, but what would matlab place there for a random vector? Otherwise, for your example, it is just `([a 5] + [0 a]) / 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a = [1,2,3,4], i want it to produce b = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5 ]

There is no need in loop

```
b = (a(1 : end - 1) + a(2 : end)) / 2;
```

Another way

```
b = a(1 : end - 1) + diff(a) / 2;
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I misread the question so sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2):

another way,

```
conv(a,[1 1]./2,'valid')
```